# I want to export everything in the DSpace assetstore

Tags: dspace

I want to export everything in the DSpace assetstore using DSpace export -t COLLECTION -i, But it requests me to enter collection handle, but i don't know where to find it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you navigate to a collection in the UI, the handle will be a part of the URL.

See the following Collection on the DSpace Demo Site: http://demo.dspace.org/xmlui/handle/10673/2

The collection handle is 10673/2